# Bad Errors for PropType (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My code seems to be throwing incorrect PropType errors.

```
SomeComponent = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        someFunction: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
    },
...});

SomeOtherComponent = React.createClass({
    internalFunction: function(){
        console.log('test!');
    },
    render: function(){
        return <SomeComponent someFunction={this.internalFunction}/>
    }
...});
```

Getting that console.log to trigger isn't a problem at all, but I'm getting a prop type mismatch error on the `func` in the console as soon as the page loads.

How is it possible to have an error message *and* have access to the function?

Comment: its not an error message its a warning. its not raising an exception so its not breaking the javascript process. that being said in this example everything is laid out correctly, but check your spelling on the function names and stuff. make sure there are no typos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue.

Had `func.required` instead of `func.isRequired` on the propTypes and just completely overlooked it.  ah well.